# entity framework, how to use object query with a WHERE, AND to retrieve entity record

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to add and AND condition to my entity framework where clause, but the way I am doing it is not working. Can anyone show me how to do this the correct way please? Before adding the AND condition, the code worked fine.

```
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.Where("it.Recipe_Id=" & strRecipeId And "it.IngredientItemNumber=" & strIngredientNumber).FirstOrDefault()
```

The error I get reads as:

> Conversion from string "it.Recipe_Id=11" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use the built in linq if you can.  It will check your values at compile time for you and you won't get nasty surprises at run time.  You can use magic-strings of course but why not use one of the best features of of an ORM? Imagine updating a tables field type, the compiler will automatically let you know every place you need to update your code.  Instead of having forgetting about one and then having it crash here and there.

If you're querying a single table, often it's easier to put the 'wheres' inside the FirstOrDefault();

```
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = 

myContext.RefineRecipeStep
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Recipe_Id.Equals(strRecipeId) &&
                              x.IngredientItemNumber == strIngredientNumber);

if(myRecipeStepHistory != null)
{
     // 
}
```

You may have to cast your values so it matches the correct data type for Recipe_Id and IngredientItemNumber.

Comment: Hi Peter, is it possible you show me how the code would be in vb.net? what would be x in my code it? I ask because I used a code converter and this is what I got and I am unsure if it is correct: 
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Recipe_Id.Equals(strRecipeId) AndAlso x.IngredientItemNumber = strIngredientNumber)
 thanks

Comment: I tried running it but i get syntax errors. I replaced x with it but it does not like it :/

Comment: @itortu You should cast the strings to the appropriate type and (I think) in VB.Net you can just use Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Recipe_Id = recipeId AndAlso x.IngredientItemNumber = ingredientNumber). This assumes you cast the strings to variables named recipeId and ingredientNumber.

Comment: Hi itortu, sorry was offline last night. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

may be a space is missing and/or a " is missplaced:

```
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.Where("it.Recipe_Id=" & strRecipeId.ToString() & " And it.IngredientItemNumber=" & strIngredientNumber.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation and I got a new error: The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation. Near equals expression, line 6, column 44.
Points to line: Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.Where("it.Recipe_Id=" & strRecipeId & " And it.IngredientItemNumber=" & strIngredientNumber).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: which one error? I edit mys syntaxe to use .ToString()

Comment: Recipe_Id is an int data type in the database, and IngredientNumber is nvarchar(20). The line looks like: **Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.Where("it.Recipe_Id=" & CType(strRecipeId, Int32) & " And it.IngredientItemNumber=" & strIngredientNumber.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()**
The error: **The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation. Near equals expression, line 6, column 44.**

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, if you are using EF, your model already knows about RefineRecipeStep, and thus you shouldn't be writing sql in place like that?

Thus what you want becomes something more like:

```
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep
  .Where((it) => it.Recipe_Id.Equals(recipeId))
  .Where((it) => it.IngredientItemNumber.Equals(ingredientNumber))
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

or possibly:

```
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep
  .Where((it) => it.Recipe.Id.Equals(recipeId))
  .Where((it) => it.IngredientItemNumber.Equals(ingredientNumber))
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

if recipe is a known relationship...

Comment: I tried both of your recommendation but I get: ')' expected, right after: FirstOrDefault() but adding an extra parenthesis does not correct it.
Dim myRecipeStepsHistory = myContext.RefineRecipeStep.Where((it) >= it.Recipe_Id.Equals(strRecipeId).Where((it) >= it.IngredientItemNumber.Equals(strIngredientNumber)).FirstOrDefault())
Can you see where the issue might be?

Comment: oops, missing brackets added!